# Facebook Connect : auth_token parameter

Tags: facebook

I am implementing a facebook connect based application, and when I use

`$facebook->require_login()`

I am redirected to the application page, after being presented with a login page on facebook. Now, when the application page loads, a "auth_token" parameter is appended to the end, e.g:

```
http://example.com/some_path/?auth_token=892a70ff0e1c1111
```

Everytime I refresh this page, this parameter keeps getting appended to the URL, like:

```
http://example.com/some_path/?auth_token=892a70ffb1f9a2ef85be&auth_token=fc3ff94d1f92393557&auth_token=9a700b3db561e07e480de0f&auth_token=8156c4bdfb10b42&auth_token=8e56f1d962c510925580bf
```

How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=49633